# what does it mean when there exist both declaration of variable and its extern declaration in the same file?

Tags: c, variables, extern

While I analyze some source codes, I found following definitions **in one file(.c), not different file** (This is one of the codes in a file produced by flex and there is no included file(stdio.h, string.h, errno.h, stdlib.h, inttypes.h) that defines yyin ):

```
extern FILE *yyin, *yyout;

FILE *yyin = (FILE*) 0, *yyout = (FILE *) 0;
```

I basically know what these statements mean.

But, extern keyword is used to make use of definitions such as variable, and function that live in another file. (It does not allocate memory for it.)

So, what I mean is that the code :

```
FILE *yyin = (FILE*) 0, *yyout = (FILE *) 0;
```

has to appear in another file, not in the same file.

For instance,

```
a.c

extern File *yyin;  /* It means that a.c want to use yyin declared in b.c */

int main(void) {
   yyin = *expressions*; /* yyin is variable in b.c */

   return 0;
}

b.c

File *yyin = (FILE*) 0;
```

Why do they exist in the same file? Are there any special meanings when extern keyword and normal variable declaration using same name live in the same file?

Comment: If you think about how `#include` works, you will realize that it's normal for the translation unit with the definition to also have the extern declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first declaration is unusual in that it specifies `extern` explicitly, rather than relying on the default. Since the variables are declared in the file scope, they have external linkage by default, i.e. in your case the declaration is equivalent<sup>*</sup> to

```
FILE *yyin, *yyout;
```

Recall that each variable has a *scope*, *storage duration*, and *linkage*. Keyword `extern` specifies that a variable has external linkage; other options for linkage are `static` and no linkage.

Variables can have multiple declarations. As long as multiple declarations do not conflict with each other, C compiler can combine them.

In your case variables `yyin` and `yyout` have a declaration that says the variables have external linkage, and a definition that initializes both variables to `NULL`.

<sup>*</sup>The reason it is equivalent is that there are no other declarations of `yyin` and `yyout`. In general, a declaration without `extern` could become a definition if no other definition is provided in the same translation unit. This is called *tentative definition*. The declaration with `extern` does not become a tentative definition.

Comment: So, in my case, although global variable has external linkage by default, using extern keyword here explicitly means it explicitly tells it has external linkage.
Am I right?

Comment: @user7159879 Right. This is an unusual way to declare a usual global variable.

Comment: With and without `extern` is not exactly the same thing. Without `extern` it could be a *tentative definition*, with `extern` it can't.

Comment: @JensGustedt You are right, thank you for the note. I edited the answer to include an explanation.